# PayPal Buy Now with SQL database update

Tags: mysql, sql, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How would I go about creating a Buy now paypal button for a website. And having a textbox where the buyer can enter some text and when they buy "as in the payment works instantly" have the string be added to a database?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a CMS? What language have you written your site in?

PayPal provide APIs for multiple language and code which can be generated for dynamic buttons. Have you looked through the developer documentation? First sign up for a developer account and assess the options that are available for you. [PayPalAPI Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/)

I think you want to achieve a "Sale" through PayPal rather than an Authorization -> Capture and store the unique PayPal reference to SQL against an order!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive Paypal payments , you must deploy some code on you web-server .
API documentation is here :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/#

And very important you can test all your workflows with **Paypal sandbox**
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/